# Java XSD: validate only by mandatory

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd

I have the follow XSD validation:

```
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory
           .newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(new File(xsdPath));
validator = schema.newValidator();
Source xml = new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml));
validator.validate(vastXml);
```

How can I validate the XML only by mandatory fields/elements `(minOccur>0, use="required")`
i.e if there is a contenct in the XML that is not in the XSD the validation will be succesfull.
Only if one of the mandatory fields is missing it will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML Schema supports placeholders for elements that are not defined in the schema, but this is independent from `minOccurs` attributes:

```
<xs:any processContents="lax"/>
```

You can adjust:

- The namespace of the elements with a `namespace` attribute:

  ```
  <xs:any namespace="##any" processContents="lax"/>
  <xs:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax"/>
  <xs:any namespace="##local" processContents="lax"/>
  <xs:any namespace="##targetNamespace" processContents="lax"/>
  <xs:any namespace="http://www.example.com" processContents="lax"/>
  ```
- How strict they should be handled. In your case, `lax` will make sure that the XML document validates even if the elements are not defined. `strict` would, however, require that a schema definition exists. `skip` would simply accept anything.

  ```
  <xs:any namespace="##any" processContents="lax"/>
  <xs:any namespace="##any" processContents="strict"/>
  <xs:any namespace="##any" processContents="skip"/>
  ```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check some of the constraints but not others, the only way is to modify the schema so it only includes the constraints you want to check. I don't think any schema processor will allow you to be selective in terms of checking against some constraints but not others.